# Using PHP to get the colour of image

Tags: php

I'm using a colour scale from blue to red, which is a PNG set at 100px wide. I would like to define a specific range i.e. pixels 10-14 and extract the colours from there.

Is this at all possible with PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [imagecolorat()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) function is exactly what you want.